# Command Prompt and batch files

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to copy a number of files from a directory. I want to include the file path from the base of this particular directory tree, however, I only have a list of the file names to go by. Is there a way to copy either:

1. a list of files with their directories appended to the beginning in a .txt file
2. a copy of the folders in the directory with copies of the files placed in their original places in the original directory.

Each file in the directory has a unique name.

I've looked all over google, but the closest I've found is xcopy, which I don't believe is capable of this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second option you can use `xcopy /s` or `robocopy /s`. Both are great tools for this kind of job.